# Show negative values in donut plot in plotly as seperate arc

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to make a donut plot with two circles. One (outer) with positive values, other (inner) with negative values. (See attached image)

**DATA** :

```
a <- cbind.data.frame(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), c(-1, 2:4, -2, 3))
colnames(a) <- c("X", "Y")
a$flag <- ifelse(a$Y > 0 , 1, 0)
```

**CODE**:

```
bar <- ggplot(data = a, aes(x = flag, y = Y, fill = X)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +  xlab("") + ylab("Percentage Impacts")
pie <- bar + coord_polar("y", start = 0.07) 
pie
```

**PLOT:**

[image: Sample plot I made with ggplot2]

I am trying to replicate this on plotly. Is this possible?

Or any other way to show positive as well as negative values (I am not looking for bar plots. Pie is preferable)